# Write a file containing ASP delimiters

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

We have lots of files containing image / static file references to resources on our site. As we are moving these files to S3 hosting, I am writing a script that reads each of our ASP files, replaces each reference so that each one points at a globally defined variable, and rewrites those changes to the file, so that we don't have to update all these files manually!

This works alright with references inside actual code.

eg.

```
Response.Write "<img src=""http://www.site.com/images/image.gif"">"
```

becomes

```
Response.Write "<img src=""" & s3BucketName & "/images/image.gif"">"
```

But when it comes to replacing code like this :

```
<script src="/javascript/script.js">
```

It's more difficult - as we have to place the ASP delimiters <%= %> 
around the global var around it.

eg.

```
<script src="<%=s3BucketName%>/javascript/script.js">
```

Because the script delimiters actually stop the page where they are, and generate an error, that's what I'm finding difficult. URLencoding the <%=s3BucketName%> string, and writing, just writes the encoded text (unusable by ASP), doesn't transform into what I want.

Any ideas gratefully received.

Thanks, Adam

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've come up with a solution, seems to work. If you find a better one, please comment.

```
textToReplace = "src="""& chr(60) & chr(37) & chr(61) & "s3BucketName" & chr(37) & chr(62) & "/javascript/script.js"
```

Basically each symbol of <%= and %> is converted into chr() values.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the basetag in the head section of your pages then you can leave the relative urls like your script example alone, you can combine this technique with the one peedeeaay suggests.

```
<base href="http://www.s3bucketdomain.com/directory/" />
```